# Azure: map Network drive to local computer

Tags: azure

I have a Azure VPS. I access it using RDP using it's ip. Is it possible to sghare a folder onb the VPS and connect to it from Windows Explorer on my local computer like I do with other pc's in my network?

Typing \\ in windows explorer times out.
Do I have to create endpoints? If so, what are the port numbers?
I am not lookking for a VPN, just a simple solution...
Thanks,

Marc

Answer (score 1):

When you are starting up Remote Desktop Connection click on "Show Options" then "Local Resources".  When you're on that tab click the "More" button at the button and you'll see "Drives" in the window that pops up.

This will work well for small files or directories, but for anything larger you would probably be better off installing Filezilla Server or configuring IIS FTP on your remote server for FTP.

Copy and pasting files is also supported in RDP, if "Clipboard" is selected in Local Resources.